# NSCocoaError code 260

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

This error appeared when I was updating the pods to work with Swift 3 and Xcode 8:

> The file “GoogleToolboxForMac.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/ahmedhossam/Desktop/mmmm/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.xcconfig)
>   error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “GoogleToolboxForMac.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/ahmedhossam/Desktop/mmmm/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd051395a50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
>   warning: no umbrella header found for target 'GoogleToolboxForMac', module map will not be generated

Answer (score 4):

Deintegrating and installing the pods again worked for me. Navigate to the project folder in the terminal and simply use the following commands.

```
pod deintegrate 
pod install
```